# How do I print backslash followed by newline with printf?

Tags: bash, python, c

Using Python, I get

```
$ python3 -c 'print("\\\n")'
\

$
```

That is, one backslash and one newline, followed by an extra newline inserted by the interpreter.

Using C, compiling the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("\\\n");
    return 0;
}
```

into a file `backslash.out` yields

```
$ ./backslash.out 
\
$
```

That is, one backslash and one newline.

In bash, I get

```
$ STRING="\\\n"
$ printf "${STRING}"
\n$
```

What exactly is the bash printf command doing here? What is it doing differently from the python `print` or C `printf` commands with respect to the escape character `\`? And what will I need to put in the variable `STRING` to obtain the following output on my terminal:

```
$ printf "${STRING}"
\
$
```

Comment: I think it's more a matter of what the shell does to (weak quoted) `"\\n"` *before* passing it to `printf` - compare `printf '\\\n'` for example

Comment: So the shell turns `\\\n` into `\\n`, which is fed to `printf`, which then turns it into `\n`?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant `"\\\n"` - if you want to use a variable, then try hard-quoting the string and then using printf's `%b` format: `string='\\\n' ; printf '%b' "$string"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your snippet below, you use "double quotes" around the backslash escapes:

```
$ STRING="\\\n"
$ printf "${STRING}"
\n$
```

However, Bash still evaluates some backslash-escapes inside double quotes, so the content of your variable after that is really `\\n`, as `"\\"` evaluates to `\`.

Put the string in 'single quotes' to prevent the shell from touching any of the backslashes:

```
$ STRING='\\\n'
$ printf "$STRING"
\
$
```

Comment: Alternatively: With double quotes, put `STRING="\\\\\\n"`.